# git submodule update --init gives error fatal: Needed a single revision Unable to find current revision in submodule path

Tags: git, jenkins

When i execute `git submodule update --init` I get error

> fatal: Needed a single revision Unable to find current revision in submodule path 'plugins/pluginname'.

Actually I was trying to run a Jenkins Job to deploy it. I added Recursively update submodules as additional behavior in Jenkins. FATAL: Command "git.exe submodule update --init --recursive" returned status code -1: This is occurring only from my local as same command is working for others.

Comment: I just ran into this same issue. It turns out that git couldn't communicate with the server as I needed to accept the host key that doesn't show up during submodule update (but does if you do a pull). After accepting the hostkey, everything started working as expected.

Answer (score 45):

Try `git submodule foreach git pull`

Comment: Please provide some more commentary on what this command does, which question you are answering, and how it answers that question.

Comment: This command unblocked something. After that I was able to update submodules just fine.

`git submodule foreach git pull origin master`

Comment: @EricLeschinski I would like to, but it works like a magic, not knowing the root cause which unblocked the process.

Comment: for me I had to add --depth=1: git submodule foreach git pull --depth=1 , because it was pulling a lot of commits !

Comment: This worked for me, but I'd love to know why! TortoiseGit said something about "bad object" when I looked at the changes, but now doesn't complain anymore. Seems like something went wrong with the original commit?

Comment: It's important to note that if you have nested submodules, you might want to do `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin master` instead

Comment: @EricLeschinski Sorry, I would like to, but I do not know the root cause either.

Comment: I think the issue is that Git couldn't fetch the commit from the submodule's remote earlier, maybe during a `git pull` in the superproject. `git submodule foreach git fetch` (potentially preceded by `git submodule sync` to sync the remote URL) fixes that, and then `git submodule update` can check out the correct commit. Weirdly enough, it looks like the latter command is supposed to run `git fetch` by itself, but for some reason it doesn't. Git bug?

Answer (score 9):

It's an example of a **hidden actual error**, a UX pitfall typical to Git.

In my case the real error was that I was using a submodule pinned to a branch that doesn't exist anymore (e.g. feature branch that was already merged and deleted via Gitlab). Verify if that's the case for you as well and if it is, point the submodule to a new branch.

Comment: But then I have to do this for many submodules where this is the case, this is alot of work. I guess submodules are still in alpha version. So many problems.

Comment: This happened for us because our branch names were changed from `master` to `main` and `master` didn't exist

Answer (score 7):

I tried many other suggestions that didn't work, but the commands that worked for me are:

```
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init
```

Comment: Actually that is what we already do. Still from time to time we're getting the error mentioned above.

Comment: THANK YOU Fred! I was stuck for hours trying every combination of 'git submodule foreach ..." and this is the only thing that ended up working.

Answer (score 3):

An older question, but here's what worked for me.

The error happens because the fetch command the `git submodule update` runs isn't finding the branch. In my case, I could sync and update all I wanted but it still didn't fix it. I eventually found my solution in a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58666947/5791702), but I'm adding here for anyone else runs into it.

If the parent repo was shallowly cloned, then `remote.origin.fetch` in the submodule is restricted to the branch set in the `.gitmodule` (or the default branch). In my case, I was only running into the problem with Gitlab CI when I was trying to run tests from the parent repo on a branch of the submodule. Submodules worked fine if `.gitmodules` is modified as part of a commit, but not if changing branch on the runner itself.

If you're running into this error you can check/fix your submodules with:

```bash
git submodule foreach git config --get remote.origin.fetch
# Entering 'good_submodule'
# +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
# Entering 'bad_submodule'
# +refs/heads/someBranch:refs/remotes/origin/someBranch
```

And you can similarly correct it:

```bash
# selectively fix
git -C bad_submodule config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
# ensure all submodules can access everything
git submodule foreach git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

Answer (score -4):

what worked for me is updating git-bash